# How to download file using volleyplus library

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I am using volley `com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0` library to make normal requests and it is working fine. Now required is to download a pdf file too. For that I need to use volleyplus `dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+`

Now since I have added duplicate libraries it gives me error like

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Also none of the volley class reference is found in the code.

So, how to achieve both the functionality?
There is nt any kind of image caching related requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all => invalidate cache and restart if not work then

Once I was found this error. This error mean you have duplicated library but different version in your project.
Such as :

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.y.y'
```

I have add "Retrofit2" and "OkHttp3" together but in "Retrofit" already included OkHttp3 with 3.x.x version but another OkHttp3 I have add is not 3.x.x but 3.y.Y version so it's different and show error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Please make sure don't have some duplicated library like this with [Dependency tree](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree)